# getting effect to image on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk

i want build a photography app with effects . e.g. old images with brown or black and white filter , how can i process UIImageView to change color , brightness and .... 
thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple’s [GLImageProcessing sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/) should get you started.